# R Shiny: center an absolutePanel

Tags: r, shiny

How do I centre an absolutePanel in Shiny?  I've tried setting left = 50% and it centres the left side of the panel.

```
absolutePanel(id = "myId", class = "myClass", fixed = TRUE
                    ,draggable = TRUE, top = 10, left = "50%", right = "auto", bottom = "auto"
                    ,width = 100, height = "auto"
```

Comment: Do yo want to center *inside* the panel? If so, try `left="50%", style="text-align: center;"`.

Comment: It is inside a div like this: fluidPage(absolutePanel(div(absolutePanel(id = "myId"... I tried your suggestion but it still only centres the left side of the panel, whereas I'm hoping to centre the panel on the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put inside css file:

```
#myId{margin: auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation this worked.  Inside the absolutePanel (in ui.R) set

```
absolutePanel(id = "myId", class = "myClass", fixed = TRUE
                ,draggable = TRUE, top = 0, left = 0, right = 0, bottom = 0
                ,width = 100, height = "auto", ...
```

Then in a css file set

```
#myId { 
  margin: auto;
}
```